# Can't update wordpress wp-content files via FTP

Tags: jquery, wordpress, ftp, updates

I keep getting several errors on my WordPress site. [image]
I am pretty sure that the .live is not a function is because the class it is looking for on the page does not exist. I tried to fix it via FTP but notice that Js files have a version number after them. When I update the files via FTP it does not take effect but still references the file with a version number like so  `cmb.js?ver=0.9.1`
[image]

Any ideas about how to address this issue?

Comment: I'm confused - what exactly is your question? Is it about FTP as in your title, or the jQuery errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(…).live is not a function` is popping up because WordPress uses jQuery version `1.12.4` at least, as of WordPress 5.5. `live()` was removed in jQuery `1.9`.

You'll need to use `$('body').on('click', '.cmb_upload_button', function(){ /*…*/ });` instead. (or some other parent element, `'body'` is just a safe fallback if you're unsure) - You can read more about the [`.on()` function](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

As for the version query strings on the files, those are added in the 4th argument of the [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function that is enqueueing that particular asset. You'll need to change it in whatever theme or plugin is enqueueing it.

Generally what I do, is when enqueueing a third party or library asset, I'll include the version of what I'm using: `1.12.4`, for example. Then when I upgrade that asset, I'll update it to that version. *However*, when I'm enqueueing a custom asset, I'll generally use the [`filemtime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) of the file, so that way it's always a freshly cached copy of my most recent changes:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', site_url( 'assets/js/custom-script.js' ), [], filemtime( '/absolute/path/to/js/custom-script.js' ), true );
```